# Sumar distintas tablas en SQL

Tags: sql

[image: TABLA]

Hola, pueden ayudarme con esta duda porfa?

Tengo 2 tablas distintas pero que contienen el mismo encabezado, quisiera sumar los montos dependiendo del tipo de CuentaCorriente.

```
--Mov1 es la tabla 1
--Mov2 es la tabla 2
SELECT CuentaContable, SUM(Mov1.Monto+Mov2.Monto) FROM Mov1 INNER JOIN Mov2
ON Mov1.CuentaContable=Mov2.CuentaContable
GROUP BY CuentaContable
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me sale que CuentaContable es ambiguo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ambas respuestas me dieron el resultado que esperaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dice que es ambiguo porque el campo `CuentaContable` es común en ambas tablas y debes especificar en base a cual de ambas tablas debe agruparse, ahora bien te recomiendo que ya que los campos son iguales utilices `UNION ALL` y una subconsulta para obtener el resultado que necesitas, algo así:

```
SELECT CuentaContable,SUM(Monto) Monto FROM (
SELECT CuentaContable, Monto FROM Mov1 
UNION ALL
SELECT CuentaContable, Monto FROM Mov2) a
GROUP BY CuentaContable
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas. Saludos.

Comment: una consulta... porq luego del paréntesis pones 'a'?

Comment: es un alias para la subconsulta (puedes colocar cualquiera), sin el alias no funcionaria la subconsulta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes indicar de que tabla sera donde se tomara `CuentaContable` tanto en el `SELECT` como el mismo para `GROUP BY`; por ejemplo

```
SELECT Mov1.CuentaContable, SUM(Mov1.Monto+Mov2.Monto) FROM Mov1 INNER JOIN Mov2
ON Mov1.CuentaContable=Mov2.CuentaContable
GROUP BY Mov1.CuentaContable
```

Ahora bien; en los datos que muestras (en la imagen) hay 2 valores en `CuentaContable` más sin embargo; con el `INNER JOIN` obtendrás todas las sumatorias con respecto a `Mov1` si hay otras en `Mov2` no las veras.

Si por alguna razón varian te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
SELECT TodasCuentas.CuentaContable, SUM(ISNULL(Movs1.Total, 0)+ISNULL(Movs2.Total, 0)) 
FROM (
   /* Obtenemos un SubQuery con todas las Cuentas existentes en ambas tablas */
   SELECT DISTINCT CuentaContable FROM Mov1
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT CuentaContable FROM Mov2
) TodasCuentas 
LEFT JOIN (
   // Realizamos las sumatorias por Cuenta de tabla Mov1
   SELECT CuentaContable, SUM(Monto) TOTAL FROM Mov1 GROUP BY CuentaContable
) Movs1 ON Movs1.CuentaContable = TodasCuentas.CuentaContable
LEFT JOIN (
   // Realizamos las sumatorias por Cuenta de tabla Mov2
   SELECT CuentaContable, SUM(Monto) TOTAL FROM Mov2 GROUP BY CuentaContable
) Movs2 ON Movs2.CuentaContable = TodasCuentas.CuentaContable
```

> Por la imagen que compartes asumo es SQL SERVER; por eso el `ISNULL`; dependiendo el SMBD puede ser que `ALGO` + `NULL` de como resultado `NULL` por eso mejor establecer un valor (en este caso 0) para los valores `NULL`s.